# Detecting AR Markers pose with a fisheye lense

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any general library or ROS package that is compatible with fisheye like distorted images? Until now I was undistorting my images and using the [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) package but this sacrifices the wide field of view. And what intrinsic calibration information do such programs get? (I think OpenCV 2.x.x only supports pinhole models). An alternative to estimate a monocular fisheye camera pose would also be useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201233/detecting-ar-markers-pose-with-a-fisheye-lense/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-01-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2015-10-30**:
Did you find any information about this topic? I'm also thinking about detecting markers in fisheye images. But I'm not sure if alvar can handle the distortion. Should I risk buying a fisheye camera and not being able to process the images?

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2019-06-26**:
The topic is old, but you undistort the image with [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) after calibrating the camera.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2019-06-27**:
@machinekoder the whole point was about using the full field of view of the camera to cover more space. Undistorting the image will crop a lot of that field out view out. See my old answer.

**Comment by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on 2019-06-28**:
But keep in mind undistorting should not sacrifice FOV. It just undistorts the image of the fisheye lens, which itself already loses information compared to a less distorted lens (more details on the same image sensor area). So yes, the fisheye lens can indeed improve FOV compared to a standard lens, with the cost of image quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it can handle distorted images as it probably looks for edges/corners of the makers and expects them to be of form line segments. You could use the undistorted image though but you would lose some field of view.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0